# [C#]TextFieldParser not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to read the csv you can download from here: https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/TblView/nph-tblView?app=ExoTbls&config=planets . Just click on "Download Table" and select CSV, all columns, all rows.

The code has some problems:

1. How to recognize the comment? I expect the class to simply skip them and do not put them in the fields variables. But they are.
2. Why the number of columns is wrong? They are 403 and instead it find 405. According to pandas (Python3) they are 403. In fact when I try to use TextFieldParser for more complicated operations on this csv I get some errors like OutOfBoundary related to the index of the array (of course, columns are 403 but it though they are 405).

Code:

```
private void loadData(string fileName) {

            int rows = 0;
            int columns = 0;

            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(fileName, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                parser.CommentTokens = new []{"#"};
                parser.TrimWhiteSpace = false;
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;

                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    //Process row

                    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string field in fields)
                    {
                        //TODO: Process field

                    }

                    if (fields.Length == 0) {
                        //Should be a commment
                        printLine("Comment found on row " + rows);
                    }

                    if (fields.Length > columns)
                        columns = fields.Length;

                    rows++;
                }

                printLine ("Rows: " + rows);
                printLine ("Columns: " + columns);
                printLine ("Errors on line: " + parser.ErrorLineNumber);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore the commented lines you need to change your parser.CommentTokens statement to use new string[] as below

```
   parser.CommentTokens = new string []{"#"};
```

Once you change that the comments will be ignored.  There are 3 lines in the file that have a different number of columns then the 403 that all others have

I added the check below to determine when the number of fields is greater than 403(Line 159, 3310, and 3311 have 404 and 405 columns/fields)

```
   if (fields.Length > 403)
     {
       Console.WriteLine($"Line:{lineNo} has {fields.Length}.");
     }
```

With the above at least you can do some kind of checking/cleanup on those lines that have more than the number of expected fields

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I found out that some fields include the separator (the coma). That was the problem during the parser.